# Sort an array that are merged together

Tags: ruby

I have 2 strings that I made into an array to sort then to convert back into a string. But, in my test in my response.body The given string is sorted differently. I have a method that takes 2 strings and removes the headers from both and mergers the array and sorts it. But getting different results. How can I get the desired results of the below `response.body` string

```
string1 = "Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?\nPRESENT AVAIALBLE,PRESENT AVAILABLE,No,No,\nBUG AVAILABLE,BUG,No,No,\nBUG,BUG,No,No,\nPRESENT,PRESENT,No,No\n"
```

```
string2 = "Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?\nBUG,BUG,No,No,\nBUG AVAILABLE,BUG,No,No,\nEXAMPLE 1,EXAMPLE 1,Yes,No,\nEXAMPLE 2,EXAMPLE 2,Yes,No,\nPRESENT AVAIALBLE,PRESENT AVAILABLE,No,No,\nPRESENT,PRESENT,No,No\n"
```

how would I get that array to be sorted as the response.body string before inserting the header `"Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?"`

response.body string

```
"Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?
BUG,BUG,No,No,
BUG AVAILABLE,BUG,No,No,
EXAMPLE 1,EXAMPLE 1,No,No,
EXAMPLE 2,EXAMPLE 2,Yes,No,
PRESENT,PRESENT,No,No"
PRESENT AVAIALBLE,PRESENT AVAILABLE,No,No"
```

My output from method

```
"Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?
BUG AVAILABLE,BUG,No,No,
BUG,BUG,No,No,
EXAMPLE 1,EXAMPLE 1,No,No,
EXAMPLE 2,EXAMPLE 2,Yes,No,
PRESENT AVAIALBLE,PRESENT AVAILABLE,No,No,
PRESENT,PRESENT,No,No"
```

method I wrote

```
def merge(string1, string2)
  string1 = string1.split("\n") # Split into array.
  headers = string1.first # Get headers.
  string1.shift # Remove headers.
  string2 = string2.split("\n")[1..-1] # Remove headers.
  final = (string1 + string2).sort.unshift(headers).join("\n") + "\n" # Create merged sorted string.
end
```

desired result wanted

```
"Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?
BUG,BUG,No,No,
BUG AVAILABLE,BUG,No,No,
EXAMPLE 1,EXAMPLE 1,No,No,
EXAMPLE 2,EXAMPLE 2,Yes,No,
PRESENT,PRESENT,No,No"
PRESENT AVAIALBLE,PRESENT AVAILABLE,No,No"
```

Comment: also include your desired result in question

Comment: @Dave I updated with the desired result wanted

Comment: You desired result appears to be the same as your given string.

Comment: the output from my method is not the same as the response.body string.

Comment: You say you are given two strings but you only show one. I am guessing that the two strings are `"Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden\nBUG,BUG,No,No,\nEXAMPLE 1,EXAMPLE 1,No,No,\nPRESENT,PRESENT,No,No"` and `"Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?\nBUG AVAILABLE,BUG,No,No,\nEXAMPLE 2,EXAMPLE 2,Yes,No,\nPRESENT AVAIALBLE,PRESENT AVAILABLE,No,No"`. Correct? If so you need to include that in your question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland apologies, I updated the question with the 2 strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three ways to do that.

I assume you are given two strings:

```
str1 = "Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?\nBUG,BUG,No,No\nEXAMPLE 1,EXAMPLE 1,No,No\nPRESENT,PRESENT,No,No"
```

```
str2 = "Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?\nBUG AVAILABLE,BUG,No,No\nEXAMPLE 2,EXAMPLE 2,Yes,No\nPRESENT AVAILABLE,PRESENT AVAILABLE,No,No"
```

Then

```
header, *body1 = str1.split("\n")
  #=> ["Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?",
  #    "BUG,BUG,No,No",
  #    "EXAMPLE 1,EXAMPLE 1,No,No",
  #    "PRESENT,PRESENT,No,No"]
```

so

```
header
  #=> "Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?"
body1
  #=> ["BUG,BUG,No,No",
  #    "EXAMPLE 1,EXAMPLE 1,No,No",
  #    "PRESENT,PRESENT,No,No"]
```

and

```
_, *body2      = str2.split("\n")
  #=> ["Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?",
  #    "BUG AVAILABLE,BUG,No,No",
  #    "EXAMPLE 2,EXAMPLE 2,Yes,No",
  #    "PRESENT AVAILABLE,PRESENT AVAILABLE,No,No"]
```

so

```
_ #=>  "Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?"
body2
  #=> ["BUG AVAILABLE,BUG,No,No",
  #    "EXAMPLE 2,EXAMPLE 2,Yes,No",
  #    "PRESENT AVAILABLE,PRESENT AVAILABLE,No,No"]
```

We may then compute the desired string.

```
str = [header].concat(body1.zip(body2).flatten).join("\n")
  #=> "Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?\nBUG,BUG,No,No\nBUG AVAILABLE,BUG,No,No\nEXAMPLE 1,EXAMPLE 1,No,No\nEXAMPLE 2,EXAMPLE 2,Yes,No\nPRESENT,PRESENT,No,No\nPRESENT AVAILABLE,PRESENT AVAILABLE,No,No"
```

which when displayed appears as follows.

```
puts str
Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?
BUG,BUG,No,No
BUG AVAILABLE,BUG,No,No
EXAMPLE 1,EXAMPLE 1,No,No
EXAMPLE 2,EXAMPLE 2,Yes,No
PRESENT,PRESENT,No,No
PRESENT AVAILABLE,PRESENT AVAILABLE,No,No
```

See [Array#concat](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-concat), [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-zip), [Array#flatten](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) and [Array#join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-join).

The variable `_` in `_, *body2 = str2.split("\n")` is so-named to tell the reader that it is not used in subsequent calculations. Sometimes might write `_header, *body2 = str2.split("\n")` to convey the same message.

---

Here is a second way of doing that by treating the strings as comma-delimited CSV strings.

```
require 'csv'
```

```
arr1 = CSV.parse(str1)​
  #=> [["Category Name", "Code", "Enabled?", "Category Hidden?"],
  #    ["BUG", "BUG", "No", "No"],
  #    ["EXAMPLE 1", "EXAMPLE 1", "No", "No"],
  #    ["PRESENT", "PRESENT", "No", "No"]],

arr2 = CSV.parse(str2)
  #=> [["Category Name", "Code", "Enabled?", "Category Hidden?"],
  #    ["BUG AVAILABLE", "BUG", "No", "No"],
  #    ["EXAMPLE 2", "EXAMPLE 2", "Yes", "No"],
  #    ["PRESENT AVAILABLE", "PRESENT AVAILABLE", "No", "No"]]
```

Then

```
str = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << arr1.shift
  arr2.shift
  until arr2.empty? do
    csv << arr1.shift
    csv << arr2.shift
  end
end
  #=> "Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?\nBUG,BUG,No,No\nBUG AVAILABLE,BUG,No,No\nEXAMPLE 1,EXAMPLE 1,No,No\nEXAMPLE 2,EXAMPLE 2,Yes,No\nPRESENT,PRESENT,No,No\nPRESENT AVAILABLE,PRESENT AVAILABLE,No,No\n"
```

```
puts str
Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?
BUG,BUG,No,No
BUG AVAILABLE,BUG,No,No
EXAMPLE 1,EXAMPLE 1,No,No
EXAMPLE 2,EXAMPLE 2,Yes,No
PRESENT,PRESENT,No,No
PRESENT AVAILABLE,PRESENT AVAILABLE,No,No
```

See [CSV::parse](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse) and [CSV::generate](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-generate).

---

This can also be done without converting the strings to arrays, manipulating those arrays to form a single array and then converting the single array back to a string.

```
arr = [str1, str2]
str_indices = 0..str1.count("\n") 
arr_indices = 0..arr.size-1
idx_begin = Array.new(arr.size, 0)

puts str_indices.each_with_object("") do |i, str|
  arr_indices.each do |j|
    idx_end = arr[j].index(/(?:\n|\z)/, idx_begin[j])
     s = arr[j][idx_begin[j]..idx_end]
     s << "\n" unless s[-1] == "\n" || (i == str_indices.last && j == arr_indices.last)
     str << s unless i.zero? && j > 0
     idx_begin[j] = idx_end + 1
  end
end
Category Name,Code,Enabled?,Category Hidden?
BUG,BUG,No,No
BUG AVAILABLE,BUG,No,No
EXAMPLE 1,EXAMPLE 1,No,No
EXAMPLE 2,EXAMPLE 2,Yes,No
PRESENT,PRESENT,No,No
PRESENT AVAILABLE,PRESENT AVAILABLE,No,No
```

The regular expression `/(?:\n|\z)/` matches a newline character (`\n`) or (`|`) the end of the string (`\z`).

See the form of [String#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-index) that takes an optional second argument that specifies the string index where the search is to begin.